# How to communicate with remote PCSC reader with local PCSC application?

Tags: local, tunnel, pcsc

There is a need to use local PCSC reader application to communicate with the Smart Card which is located in the remote PCSC reader.

```
          (Windows)
| - - - - - local - - - - - |          | - - - - remote - - - - |
 PCSC app <-> virtual PCSC <-> tunnel <-> tunneling PCSC app <-> SCard
```

What are the options to do this kind of remote card communication?

- Maybe an option would be to implement virtual device for every tunneling connection instance? I don't have knowledge how to do it. I would prefer Java or .NET.

OR

- Maybe is it possible to fake winscard.dll(proxy) by just putting it into PCSC applications folder?

I would like to implement tunneling PCSC app at remote side as a java web applet.

Do you have any good suggestions or additional options how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCT claims to have something like this: http://www.opensc-project.org/openct.

Also you can get Smartcard readers with Ethernet, their drivers do something like this.

Comment: Well.. I found that this dll wrapping can be done. There can be implemented Mixed Mode C++ dll. Good starting point is here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically. The only thin is that you can't call your .NET related stuff from __E__0__() like native functions straight. As well you cant initialize your .NET objects in constructor, because VM between Managed and Unmanaged C++ cant be run there. You have to call Managed function fron native function as mixed. This way the VM gets started. But still I found another workaround by undocumented functionality